# Post Kendo Grid data to Controller in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, grid

I have two classes. One that contains a list of the other class:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Surname { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
public List<Models.Occupation> Occupations { get; set; }
```

The second class is as follows

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Industry { get; set; }
```

My controller rendering the view

```
Person p = new Person()
{
     Name = "megan",
     Surname = "du Preez",
     Id = 0,
     Age = 22
 };
 return View(p);
```

In the view

```
@model Models.Person

<form id="person">
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(mp => mp.Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(mp => mp.Surname)
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.Occupation>()
        .Name("Occupations")
        .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Bound(e => e.Name);
                columns.Bound(e => e.Industry);
            })
        )
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Occupations_Read", "People", new { Name = Model.Name}))
        )
    </div>

    @Html.Kendo().Button().Name("btnTest").Content("Create")
```

This reads the persons occupations as follows

```
List<Models.Occupation> oc = new List<Models.Occupation>();
oc.Add(new Models.Occupation() { CategoryName = "Lecturer" });
oc.Add(new Models.Occupation() { CategoryName = "Student" });
oc.Add(new Models.Occupation() { CategoryName = "Janitor" });

return Json(oc.ToDataSourceResult(request));
```

All this renders my view and it all works, but on the forms post I want to send everything back to the action

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PersonPost(Models.Person p)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

I can easily post the Person's name and Surname using the following javascript

```
$("#btnTest").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Tasks/PersonPost",
        type: 'POST',
        data: $('#person').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

        }
    });
});
```

but the occupations in the grid do not get serialized and posted back to the controller action.

My question is how can I post the whole model with the list of occupations from the view to the controller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this..

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Models.Occupation>()
    .Name("Occupations")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.Name).ClientTemplate("#= Name # <input type='hidden' name='Occupation[#=index(data)#].Name' value='#= Name #' />");
        columns.Bound(e => e.Industry).ClientTemplate("#= Industry # <input type='hidden' name='Occupation[#= index(data)#].Industry' value='#= Industry#' />");
    })        
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Occupations_Read", "People", new { Name = Model.Name}))
    )

[HttpPost]
public JsonResult PersonPost(Models.Person p)
{
    //do stuff
}
```

you should be able to get values in Person.
 please add the following function..
*****************************Javascript***************************

```
 //Index function for the WorkOrder Create view
        function index(dataItem) {

            var data = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
            return data.indexOf(dataItem);
        }
```

## Shaz

Comment: This worked wonderfully!! Only problem was that index(data) gave me a script error so I just added an Id property to my Occupation class and said #= Id# instead

Comment: Thank you so much! Works brilliantly!

Comment: NO prob...just keep that in mind . index(dataItem) by default run where ever you do CRUD operation on grid..so its a very powerful function .you can do custome things as dataitem is also deafult param from grid..

Comment: I followed your answer, it's working very good, but if I have hierarchies in grid, I don't know how to do.

I really happy if getting your answer, thanks

Comment: Instead of having to specify the grid in the index, you could make it more general by defining it such: `function index(dataItem) { return dataItem.parent().indexOf(dataItem); }`

Answer (score 3):

The grid data isn't in form elements. The form elements appear only when a cell is being edited, then it is removed. You can't post the data to the server by using a form submit button.

The proper way to to this would be by adding the 'save' command button that the grid provides itself:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Invoice.Models.ViewModels.SegmentViewModel>()
    .Name("Segment")
    .ToolBar(toolbar => {
        toolbar.Save(); // add save button to grid toolbar
    })
    // ... rest of options ...
```

Or by calling saveChanges() on the Grid widget:

Save Segments

```
$("#save").on("click", function () {
    $("#Segment").data("kendoGrid").saveChanges();
});
```

Comment: Off course, this will mean that if you want to save the data on your view in one take, you will have to take steps to make sure that it happens that way. Myself, in similar scenarios, I've choose to implement a popup to edit collections, adding each "row" to the view as form elements.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this script on your event:

```
function SaveUserProjectDetails() {

        var postUrl;
        var paramValue;

        var gridData = $("#CustomerInfoKendoGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();
        postUrl = '@Url.Content("~/Billing/CustomerAccountManage/GetDepartmentWiseCategoryList")';
        paramValue = JSON.stringify({ CustomerInformationList: gridData });


        $.ajax({
            url: postUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: paramValue,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function (objAjaxRequest, strError) {
                var respText = objAjaxRequest.responseText;
                console.log(respText);
            }
        });

    }
```

**CustomerInformationList** is your grid source list.
For more details [see this](http://atikpassion.blogspot.com/2014/06/post-kendo-grid-data-with-model-data-to.html)

Answer (score 1):

What about an solution like this:

```
$( document ).ready(
   $("form").each(function(i, form){
       $(this).find(".k-grid").each(function(_i, div){
           $(form).submit(div, kendoGridSubmitData);
       });
    });
);

function kendoGridSubmitData(e) {
    var lModel = e.data.id;
    var lKendoGrid = $(e.data).data("kendoGrid");

    // Iterate over all rows
    lKendoGrid.dataItems().forEach(function(_row, _rowIndex){
        // Iterate over all fields
        _row.forEach(function(_value, _name){
            // Add the input hidden
            $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                id: lModel,
                name: lModel+'['+_rowIndex+'].'+_name,
                value: _value
            }).appendTo('form');
        });
    });
}
```